# Items not visible after building or events not working

Tags: events, build, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a really simple app : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#AREBJ . It consists of a view, which displays some links. After clicking each of them, a popup with target value appears. Everything works fine before building the app, but after building the links are not displayed at all. For showing links I'm using the DataView component. Previously I've tried tackling it with Ext.Component, but dunno why events were not fired when any of the items was tapped on (and 'paint' event as well). Here's the second version of IconsScreen view which I'd prefer to use, but without events it's useless :

```
Ext.define('SF.view.IconsScreen', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'icons-screen',
    require: [
        'SF.store.MainMenu'
    ],
    config: {
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<ul class="menu-icons-list">',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<li class="icon">',
                    '<a target="{url}" style="background: url({icon})">',
                    '</a>',
                    '<span class="icon-text">{name}</span>',
                '</li>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</ul>'
        ),
        store : Ext.create('SF.store.MainMenu'),
        data : [],
        listeners : {
            painted : function(){
                this.onIconTap();
            }
        }
    },

    initialize : function() {
        var storeData = this.getStore().getRange(),
            tplData   = [];

        Ext.Array.each(storeData, function(item){
            tplData.push(item.getData());
        });

        this.setData(tplData);

        this.element.on({
            scope    : this,
            delegate : 'a',
            tap      : 'onIconTap'
        });

        this.callParent();
    },

    onIconTap : function(e, t) {
        this.fireEvent('icontap', e, t);
    }
});
```

I'm also attaching a buildable version : https://mega.co.nz/#!kEZiCTQT!ckFxSQz0qMScpIX1UvfZGxa0qeQfM9MVy8hynjdPHQ8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think your `this.element` is undefined until list is actually rendered. So you can't assign events like this in constructor. You need to wait for paint/render event and then assign additional handlers there.

As for tracking issues in built code I would suggest building `testing` version. It's not minified but it's equal to production in all other ways.

Comment: I am building the 'testing' version. I've been also assigning listeners in the afterRender function, but without any luck.

Comment: Try to add debug to see if element is defined

Comment: yup it is. Also as I've indicated in the topic - both solutions are broken only after building. That's the part I'm most concerned about :/

Comment: There are difference in how ST behaves in built and non-built environment. For example I noticed several times that some properties that are inside `config` object would be accessible directly `var.prop` in non-built code but would require `var.config.prop` in built one. If you have `testing` version build - the only way to figure this out - add debug messages and see what's going on.

Comment: Turned out that magical setTimeout(0) solved the problem. Apparently DOM wasn't ready in the built version when the listeners were assigned. Dumb sencha is dumb.